# Calculate mean and std of a variable, in a datastep in SAS

Tags: sas, datastep

I have a dataset where observations is student and then I have a variable for their test score. I need to standardize these scores like this :

```
newscore = (oldscore - mean of all scores) / std of all scores
```

So that I am thinking is using a Data Step where I create a new dataset with the 'newscore' added to each student. But I don't know how to calculate the mean and std of the entire dataset IN in the Data Step. I know I can just calculate it using proc means, and then manually type it it. But I need to do I a lot of times and maybe drop variables and other stuff. So I would like to be able to just calculate it in the same step.

Data example:

__*VAR*     testscore newscore
Student1 5         x
Student2 8  x
Student3 5 x

Code I tried:

```
data new;
set old;
newscore=(oldscore-(mean of testscore))/(std of testscore)
run;
```

(Can't post any of the real data, can't remove it from the server)

How do I do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample data and the sas code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method1:** Efficient way of solving this problem is by using **proc stdize** . It will do the trick and you dont need to calculate mean and standard deviation for this.

```
data have;
input var $ testscore;
cards;
student1 5
student2 8
student3 5
;
run;

data have;
set have;
newscore = testscore;
run;

proc stdize data=have out=want;
   var newscore;
run;
```

**Method2:** As you suggested taking out means and standard deviation from proc means, storing their value in a macro and using them in our calculation.

```
proc means data=have;
var testscore;
output out=have1 mean = m stddev=s;
run;

data _null_;
set have1;
call symputx("mean",m);
call symputx("std",s);
run;

data want;
set have;
newscore=(testscore-&mean.)/&std.;
run;
```

**My output:**

```
var           testscore  newscore
student1      5          -0.577350269   
student2      8          1.1547005384   
student3      5          -0.577350269
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Hey, thansk a lot ! 

Proc stdize did the job reallly easy.

And thanks for the other method aswell, i dident know you could use proc means to store output and then use it again. Though i just made a table. Thansk a lot !

Comment: True. But you also need to know the way to store the values and further use them without manually entering them (in this case means and standard deviation), therefore i also told the other way. You are welcome. Happy to help :)

Comment: Arh ofcourse, done, im very new here on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Why would you use macro variables to do the transfer from PROC MEANS to data step, instead of how I show it (directly with the datasets)?

Comment: I didn't know that. I have never used a set in if statement Thanks for the info though. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to do this in the data step.  Do it with `proc means`.  You don't need to type anything in, just grab the value in a dataset.

You don't provide enough to give complete code in the answer, but the basic idea.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
var height weight;
output out=class_stats mean= std= /autoname;
run;

data class;
  if _n_=1 then set class_Stats;  *copy in the values from class_Stats;
  set sashelp.class;
  height_norm = (height-height_mean)/(height_stddev);
  weight_norm = (weight-weight_mean)/(weight_stddev);

run;
```

Alternately, just use `PROC STDIZE` which will do this for you.

```
proc stdize data=sashelp.class out=class_Std;
   var height weight;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! 

I did not know proc stdize, it did the job like a charm! 

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this via proc sql:

```
proc sql; 
create table want as
select *, mean(oldscore) as mean ,std(oldscore) as sd
from have; 
quit;
```

For other statistical functions in proc sql, see here: https://support.sas.com/kb/25/279.html