# Calculating the sum of individual squared deviations in SAS

Tags: statistics, sas

I'm trying to calculate the individual squared deviations to perform some calculations based on these values.

I have the following dataset:

```
data have;
input testid $ level $ values;
datalines;
HITT1D   LC1   0.45
HITT1D   LC1   0.49
HITT1D   LC1   0.47
HITT1D   LC2   0.43
HITT1D   LC2   0.39
HITT1D   LC2   0.42
HITT1D   LC3   0.66
HITT1D   LC3   0.63
HITT1D   LC3   0.64
HBEF5D   LC1   0.45
HBEF5D   LC1   0.49
HBEF5D   LC1   0.47
HBEF5D   LC2   0.43
HBEF5D   LC2   0.39
HBEF5D   LC2   0.42
HBEF5D   LC3   0.66
HBEF5D   LC3   0.63
HBEF5D   LC3   0.64
;
run;
```

I need to calculate:

1. the sum of all individual squared deviations for each combination of testid and level
2. and the sum of of all individual squared deviations for each testid

I used the following to calculate the average for a given testid and level:

```
proc means data=have ;
    var values;
    class testid level;
    output out=class_stats mean = /autoname ;
run;
```

to subtract from the observations in order to replicate the following example:

[image: example of the aimed calculations]

in which "LOT" is equivalent to the level in the data and "subject" is equivalent to testid.

I have looked into the examples given here:
[Calculate mean and std of a variable, in a datastep in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791006/calculate-mean-and-std-of-a-variable-in-a-datastep-in-sas)
but I can not replicate them as these data only has one class.

unfortunately, I can not find an easy way of doing this as I am an R user and I'm new to SAS. does anyone has a cleaver idea on how to do this in a simple way in SAS?

thanks

Comment: Is there some test statistic you are trying to calculate that needs those sum of squares? Perhaps you want to use PROC GLM or PROC ANOVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking for the CSS statistic.
[image]

Example:

```
proc means data=have css ;
  class testid level ;
  types testid testid*level ;
  var values;
run;
```

Results:

```
The MEANS Procedure

  Analysis Variable : values

              N
testid      Obs    Corrected SS
-------------------------------
HBEF5D        9       0.0882889

HITT1D        9       0.0882889
-------------------------------


        Analysis Variable : values

                          N
testid      level       Obs    Corrected SS
-------------------------------------------
HBEF5D      LC1           3     0.000800000

            LC2           3     0.000866667

            LC3           3     0.000466667

HITT1D      LC1           3     0.000800000

            LC2           3     0.000866667

            LC3           3     0.000466667
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't know the CSS in SAS.